# Is there any way to do a clean upgrade of Windows 10 and keep Windows 7 installed apps

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, licensing, application-launch

This question was almost answered by the similar questions that appear as typing the topic.  Please be aware I have tried to provide as great as detail possible that will hopefully allow any responders to have all the information about this question that are needed.

I have Windows 7. I also own Windows 10 Pro. I use swappable drive bays where either you put a hard drive into a caddy or other device and slide it in to the case docking 5 1/4 drive. This question will cover the following drives:

- 1 4TB Windows 10
- 1 500GB Samsung 850 EVO SATA interface with Windows 7 installed and no other OS, not even Linux or VMs.
- 1 4TB game drive with products from only Steam, Uplay and Origin (those are game clients that let you play software on their own client like offering (does what Steam does when you buy a program that you have to register it)

The company product I use (note I am not in any way, shape, form, direct or indirectly involved, compensated, earn any tangible or non tangible items from the company and they won't know who I am or that there name is here unless they search for it) is Vantec EZ Swap 4. The advantage for me is allowing me to have a secure Windows hard drive and a testing platform of Windows 7 to see what does and doesn't work correctly or fix issues before applying them to my secure Windows 7 hard drive.

I have Windows 7 OS plus all my non-game application software on a Samsung (same disclaimer as used for Vantec, I get nothing not even a thanks) 850 SSD SATA interface. I have a 4TB  hard drive that will be used to house Windows 10, when I am ready to start using it. Please note I have valid licenses for Windows 7 and 10 and all software is licensed or paid for. The other 4TB mentioned above is the game drive.

Now the thought of having to reinstall all those programs for my 4TB HDD Windows 10 I don't like that option. I have cleared with as many companies I can, their policy regarding having a licensed version on two hard drives and two Windows versions. Those that have replied said that if only one version of its software is running they don't have a problem. If I want to give a hard drive to someone who just happens to have the same parts, right down to Intel chipset, then no. Essentially it boiled down to only 1 license can be in use. They also stated that since it will be on the same computer, part for part, chipset, memory, GPU, etc., that it would not be illegal using their software.

A small number of companies said they have never been asked that question and they give an OK and will just need to speak to their tech department/customer support when the license contacts their validation server every time I use their software on let's say I registered it for Windows 7 and when Windows 10 causes the app to stop functioning as a full version, just remind them so they can clear the issue.

Two companies responded with no, you can't do this, however we can sell you the rights to a second license so you can have it installed in Windows 10 and Windows 7.

I am aware that installing software is how the registry is designed to handle applications and how it responds to request by the program. So for example someone trying to use an old version of Photoshop (before it went all subscription) they own and copy over just the directories that contain the Photoshop program, will find the program will not work as the registry entries will be missing.

I am not sure how to add the game drive into this, but it won't have any OS on it, so it would be finding a way to get the games also recognized by Windows 10.

Questions:

1. Is there a software program that will allow me to transfer product specific registry entries into Windows 10 and makes any adjustment for structural or coding change in Windows 10? I want to be able to do a clean install of Windows 10 before duplicating the installed programs without having to reinstall them a second time.

   If there is no software that can do this, obviously I would assume software that clones or backup lets say my Windows 7 and applications would simply erase Windows 10 totally and put Windows 7 only on the 4TB drive for Windows 10. Drivers will also be different in some cases and would require removal and updating.
2. If I clone the 500GB Samsung 850 EVO that is running Windows 7 Pro 64-bit, to that 4TB HDD and then do an install over Windows 7 (essentially an upgrade to Windows 10) will that allow me to avoid installing my applications, or even my games a second time?
3. Partial duplicate to question 1 above, if I do a factory fresh install of Windows 10 onto that 4tb HDD, are there options that I haven't mentioned, but are out on the net and are considered legal to make this transfer of Windows 7 content to Windows 10 without reinstalling?
4. If the 3 above questions/ideas won't work, what would you recommend that would be faster than reinstalling the applications again? If possible open source or low cost options first.

---

Edit: I added the game drive that will also need to be handled essentially the same by allowing me to save internet bandwidth (I have a monthly limit of 1TB) and time (especially since all these games are installed from the company server)

Comment: If you keep anything its not considered "clean". Your title terminology is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upgrade Windows 7 to Windows 10 without losing any data or installed software (assuming all software is compatible, if it's not Windows installer will warn you which incompatible programs would be removed in the process). This is done by inserting a Windows installation media (DVD or flash drive prepared using the official Windows ISO) and running `setup.exe`. The wizard will guide you through the process. Make full disk backup first.

Comment: You can do it without even needing any external media - just download the Media Creation Tool to "this computer" then run & update "this computer". You even still get your free Win10 upgrade that way, no serial required.

Comment: So just clone the SSD to the 4tb HDD, then take 4tb with the same install that is on the SSD and upgrade that with Windows 10 (I recently downloaded the most current version of Windows 10 as all the ones I have are at minimum, 1 1/2 or older.)  but will SSD being cloned to HDD make issues with the partition table of HDD (since there is OverPro of 18% on SSD - made large as helping last longer) and I remember something about an offset when cloning SSD <-> HDD.  The first time I used media create tool, it made my secure drive BSOD as it had left files unrelated to w7 that I removed

Comment: Cloning should work just fine. Overprovisioning doesn't matter in this case.

Answer (score 2):

A "clean" install means the disk is formatted as part of the installation, deleting all previous data and applications.

So, by definition, you cannot do both a "clean" install AND keep previous applications.

Data can be stored on other drives or partitions and does not actually hook into the OS, and so can be carried across while the install is still considered clean.